# Index gets out of sync on bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I have a strange problem with my SQL Server database.
I am writing bulk data (about 90,000 rows) using `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` and I am also writing about 30,000 rows in batches of 1,000 using EF's `AddRange`.

This causes the indexes on these tables to go out of sync and queries take many factors longer than usually (timeout after 10 minutes instead of a result after a few seconds).

After I manually rebuild the indexes, the queries are fast again until another of these imports is happening.

My understanding of bulk loading is that it should also update the index.
My question is: Is there a well-known reason for this behavior? If not, how can I go about trouble shooting this?

Comment: My two thoughts are statistics on the table/index and maybe fragmentation, but probably not so much fragmentation.

Comment: @dfundako Thanks for your comment. Could you expand on this comment a bit? I can't really translate it into tasks / next steps. Thanks.

Comment: Much smarter people than I can explain it better: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/sql-server-statistics-questions-we-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Comment: So, index updates are transactionally consistent with data updates in SQL server. An out of date index would indicate data corruption. I'm not saying that you don't have a problem with performance, but I'd be surprised if your indexes were out of date with respect to the base data.

Comment: @dfundako Thanks, that link was helpful

Comment: You could also check out your execution plans pre insert and post insert and see if the query optimizer changes up the plan based on the new data.

Comment: @dfundako I found trace flag 2371 - let's see if that helps. See also my answer below

Comment: Yeah. This is a ridiculous claim easily demonstrated to be wrong. Likely statistics are not updated properly due to threshold or this happening in the background.

Comment: @TomTom: What is a ridiculous claim?

Comment: That the index is out of sync. Statistics are not the index. Index out of sync would indicate data corruption and if that would be so easy to trigger...

Comment: @TomTom Ah yeah well and that's why you downvoted the question? Obviously, I am a developer, not a DBA and that was my understanding when I asked the question. You are welcome to post an answer that educates me and other people. But leave your attitude at home please, will ya?

Comment: Daniel, being a developer means you should know MORE than a DBA on aspects of your tools that you use (i.e. you can ignore disc layout optimization, memory tuning on a server, backup strategies, complex rights management etc., but NOT "how does an index work" and the like that you work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and answers here, I tried to figure out if I can change that 20% threshold somehow.
And indeed, there is a way to do this, using [trace flag 2371](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2011/09/07/changes-to-automatic-update-statistics-in-sql-server-traceflag-2371/)

You can enable it like this:

```
DBCC TRACEON(2371, -1)
```

I will now wait a few weeks to be sure that this fixed the problem, but I have good hopes about it.

Answer (score 3):

We have got exactly the same issue some years ago. And as dfundako suggested, the answer is the outdated statistics.
SQLServer by defaults updates the statistics if a certain percent of records was changed. This is a problem if your table has a huge number of records, so 90000 added records would not reach the required percentage of number of changed rows.
So if you want to be sure, after inserting you have either reindex you table (as you did) or update the statistics of your table

```
update statistics <your table>
```

Comment: In fact, the two tables in question have 20,000,000 and 5,000,000 rows, so each update would stay well below the 20% threshold.